# Unable to execute java jar from another java file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have an eclipse plugin project and I need to execute and external jar from the project. The jar file is in the src folder of my project. Can some one help me how to execute the jar from within the project? This is the code I have

```
startJar.java:
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","MyJar.jar");
    pb.start();
```

It doesn't work.startJar.java and MyJAr.jar are in the same folder. Help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem it is in **src** folder, it should be in **bin** folder

If you want to let it in **src** folder, you have to change path like this:

```
String path = ".."+File.separator+"bin"+File.separator+"MyJar.jar";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar",path);
pb.start();
```

It looks like this (/ or \ depends on OS):

```
../bin/MyJar.jar
```

Note: much better will be moving `.jar` file into **bin** folder

Comment: Most IDEs copy them themselves.

Comment: runned with ProcessBuilder? @MouseEvent

Comment: What's the difference, as long it exists in the bin as you said. Just pointed out that most IDEs does the job for you.

Comment: Ok, I response on problem where OP write "The jar file is in the src folder", Of course IDE can copy it, but OP told it is located in src, (there is nothing about "it exists in the bin" in my post) @MouseEvent